# Grails CXF plugin not found

Tags: gradle, grails, soap, cxf, grails-3.3.x

I am trying to implement SOAP services in my app, the best plugin I found is [CXF](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cxf), but I couln't install it, it looks like that I should put some additional repository.

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf/issues/71) in the source page, but if someone has faced this before, can share the solution plz?

Comment: Have you tried directly https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf/releases/tag/v3.1.2 ? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails.plugins/cxf?repo=grails-plugins contains up to 2.x plugin versions

Comment: Not, I want to mantain the dependencies in the build.gradle. I need the version 3.1.2 for compatibility with spring-boot 1.5 and later.

Comment: I installed the plugin using the demo project provided in the home page. After build the demo, I swith to my project and it looks like the dependency are cached and imported in my project. So it will work until I checkout the project in another computer or a clean the gradle cache folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use version 3.1.2 of the plugin, you want `org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.2`, not `org.grails.plugins:grails-cxf:3.1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plugin's documentation talks about to use the version 3.1.2, but the latest version in the [repository](https://dl.bintray.com/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/grails-cxf/) is the 3.0.9